# Custom LoginModule with JAAS and Wildfly 10.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, wildfly-10

Hey People I have the following problem. 
I have implemented an MyCustomLoginModule extends DatabseServerLoginModule and overrided the methods

`validatePassword(String inputPassword, String encryptedPassword) {
    boolean valid = false;
    String salt = ((DatabasePrincipal)getIdentity()).getSalt();
    if (inputPassword != null && ecryptedPassword != null && salt != null) {
        valid = ecryptedPassword.equals(HashGenerator.sha256Hex(inputPassword, salt));
    }
    return valid;
}`

and

`getUsersPassword() {...}`

When the user login the methods are called and everything is ok at this point. Now my problem, the user should be able to change his password from within the application so I've created a method like

```
public void changePassword() {
    // do some validations to check if all inputs are ok
    user.setPassword(newPassword);
    userDao.updateUser(user);
}
```

When the user changes his password the field in the database gets updated but at the next call of

`validatePassword(String inputPassword, String encryptedPassword) {}`

the `encryptedPassword` is the value returned from `getUsersPassword() {...}`
which returns the hashed new password but the `inputPassword` is still the initial (in this case the old) password and so the validation fails and I cant access protected area anymore and get redirected to the login page.

A workaround is to modify `changePassword` to

```
public void changePassword() {
    // do some validations
    getRequest().logout();
    user.setPassword(newPassword);
    userDao.updateUser(user);
    getRequest().login(user.login, newPassword);
}
```

This works but I'm looking for a better solution without logout and relogin the user.

Does someone know how to achive this? I'm running JSF 2.2 on Wildfly 10.1

If you need more information pls tell me.

========EDIT=========

This is the part from the standalone.xml where the security realm is described

```
<security-domain name="SHA2RealmTLO">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="de.tasklistone.security.module.login.SHA2SaltLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/MySqlTLO"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password, salt FROM User WHERE ? IN (login, email)"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM User WHERE ? IN (login, email)"/>
            <module-option name="principalClass" value="de.tasklistone.security.module.login.DatabasePrincipal"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Comment: What logic is triggering validatePassword to be invoked again within an already authenticated session I wonder?

Comment: It's Wildfly logic, we didnt change anything. Maybe there are some parameters settings to set on wildfly side? validatePassword is invoked on nearly every action the user does. I would say on every action which includes any database operations.

Comment: Maybe detail a bit more how exactly the security is implemented in your application. Do you do both authentication and authorization?

Comment: We use a security-realm defined on wildfly for authentication. The settings are
Code:  de.tasklistone.security.module.login.SHA2SaltLoginModule
Flag:   required
 The SHA2SaltLoginModule is the Class that includes validatePassword and getUsersPassword